# Dynamically change image source based on boolean value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an API call that retrieves an array of objects that looks like this
{id: 12313, isComplete: true}

```
   changeImage(isComplete: string) {
    let image = document.getElementById("icon-status") as HTMLImageElement    
    if(isComplete) {
      return image.src = '../ClientApp/images/Green.png'
    }
    return image.src = "../ClientApp/images/Grey.png";
  }
```

Basically set image.src = "green" if isComplete = true, else set image.src = "grey"

my HTML looks like this `<img src={this.changeImage(task.isComplete)} width="22" alt="" className="icon" id="icon-status"/>`

At the moment I'm getting TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to manipulate the img element in the DOM, you could use `task.isComplete` with the ternary operator to give the img element the correct `src`.

```
<img
  src={
    task.isComplete
      ? "../ClientApp/images/Green.png"
      : "../ClientApp/images/Grey.png"
  }
  width="22"
  alt=""
  className="icon"
  id="icon-status"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [image, setImage] = useState()
 
 useEffect(() => {
    if (isComplete) {
      setImage(require('../ClientApp/images/Green.png'))
    } else {
      setImage(require('../ClientApp/images/Gray.png')
    }
  }, [image])

<img
  src={image}
  width="22"
  alt=""
  className="icon"
  id="icon-status"
/>
```

Comment: Instead of [image] in the dependency list, shouldn't it be [isComplete]?